# How to route all DNS traffic to OpenDNS servers using two RT-N66U?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, opendns

My goal is to have all devices in my home network use OpenDNS servers.

I have one RT-N66U operating in Default mode, and one RT-N66U operating in AP mode.
I'm confused regarding the LAN DNS and WAN DNS settings, what they actually control.

**Will the router configuration settings below do the job of routing all DNS traffic to OpenDNS servers ?**

... details ...

RT-N66U operating in Default mode:
Administration > Wireless router mode (Default)
LAN > DHCP Server > DNS Server > 208.67.222.222
WAN > Connect to DNS Server automatically > No, DNS Server1: 208.67.222.222, DNS Server2: 208.67.220.220

RT-N66U operating in AP mode:
Administration > AP mode
LAN > Connect to DNS Server automatically > Yes

Comment: LAN DNS is normally what your DHCP service will hand to each client connected to it (so LAN DNS could be primary OpenDNS, secondary RT-N66U). Then when a LAN DNS request hits the RT-N66U it will use its WAN DNS to perform the DNS lookup for the incoming request.

Comment: LAN DNS setting on Default mode router only has one IP address to hand out, which is now set to OpenDNS. Should that perhaps be left blank ?! Any cmdline tools magic that can trace the DNS traffic ?

Comment: That should be fine then if they are being handed out the OpenDNS IP. Well not really however you can run ipconfig /flushdns to clear any cached DNS entries then ping *hostname* (whatever you want to check) and then run ipconfig /displaydns which will display previous DNS lookups and where Windows went to get it...

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how to troubleshoot, with the DNS cache empty. Only have to learn how to interpret the answer though :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
These settings will indeed have any connected computer using DNS server 208.67.222.222.

I don't know what happens if 208.67.222.222 is down,
wheter or not 208.67.220.220 will be used.

Comment: Modified settings of Default mode router, that are more correct, and also work:

RT-N66U operating in Default mode:
Administration > Wireless router mode (Default)
LAN > DHCP Server > DNS Server > Blank
WAN > Connect to DNS Server automatically > No, DNS Server1: 208.67.222.222, DNS Server2: 208.67.220.220

Comment: As a sideeffect, a Win8 machine that had the network connection type mistakenly set to Public, stopped working.

Once reverted to Private, it started using the DNS given from the internal router (as one would expect).